# Makumba - hidden set input field

Tags: makumba

I was wondering what is the naming convention for a hidden set mak:input field on the resulting HTML page.

I've tried hunting one down with in the source, but with no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the naming convention for makumba input fields is the same whether the field is hidden or not.

The difference is mainly in whether you have an external set ( field = set some.mdd ) or internal set (set complex; field = set; field -> subField = ...), and thus whetherr you have only one input field, or a form (mak:addForm) for the set.

In the former case, the input field name is just repeated as parameter in the subsequent form action page as many times as one of the options from the list/checkboxes is selected; in the second case, each field in the subform gets a suffix of the style _1, _2, ... _n